# Asp.net-core api response WaitingForActivision

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Can someone point me into the right direction what I am doing wrong in this Api call? I am getting an odd error that I don’t know what it means. The api call should work as I tested it using VBA and I get a response with the payload. Also any feedback is welcomed.

> Id = 190, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}" - this is the response I am getting back from it

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace BarcodeScanner.Classes
{
public class Api : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _timeout;
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private HttpClientHandler _httpClientHandler;
    private readonly string _baseUrl;
    private readonly string _credentials;
    private const string MediaTypeXml = "application/xml";

    public Api(string baseUrl, string authToken, TimeSpan? timeout = null)
    {
        _baseUrl = NormaliseBaseUrl(baseUrl);
        _credentials = Base64Encode(authToken);
        _timeout = timeout ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
    }
    public async Task<string> GetAsync(string url)
    {
        EnsureHttpClientCreated();
        using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _httpClientHandler?.Dispose();
        _httpClient?.Dispose();
    }
    private void CreateHttpClient()
    {
        _httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip
        };
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpClientHandler, false)
        {
            Timeout = _timeout
        };
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_baseUrl))
        {
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUrl);
        }
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + _credentials);
    }
    private void EnsureHttpClientCreated()
    {
        if (_httpClient == null)
        {
            CreateHttpClient();
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    //call the api
    
       try
        {
            using (var client = new Api(requestUrl, authToken))
            {
                var response = client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw new Exception("Something went wrong: ", err);
        }
```

Comment: You need to `await` things that return awaitables, in this case `client.GetAsync()`.

Comment: So what you are saying var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl); is this how it needs to be?

Comment: Correct. As it was it just queues the task but without the await you return before the task completes.

Comment: @sellotape thanks for the help that did the trick it. In vs it prompted me to change the method to async because I added that await word in there but now is getting me the right response thanks for the help.